# Django optional choices

Tags: python, django

Currently, I have the following field in my model

```
event_duration = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False,
                                                 null=False,
                                                 choices=EVENT_DURATION_OPTIONAL_CHOICES,
                                                 validators=[
                                                     MaxValueValidator(270),
                                                     MinValueValidator(1)
                                                 ],
                                                 )
```

and in my forms.py I have

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper['event_duration'].wrap(DropDownTextInput)
```

and my `DropDownTextInput`:

```
class DropDownTextInput(Field):
    """
    Layout object for rendering dropdowntextinput::

        DropDownTextInput('field_name')
    """
    template = "widgets/dropDownTextFieldRendered.html"

    def render(self, form, form_style, context, template_pack=TEMPLATE_PACK, **kwargs):
        return super(DropDownTextInput, self).render(
            form, form_style, context, template_pack=template_pack,
            extra_context={'inline_class': 'inline'}
        )
```

I want it to allow people to select from the the choices I provide, but if I they really wanted to enter their own integer, they could also do so.

It currently renders exactly like I wanted (which is the same as in [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/#buttons-with-dropdowns)), but if the user enters a value which is not in the choices list, the form becomes invalid and returns a message `Select a valid choice. 99 is not one of the available choices.`

Is there a way to set `choices` but make it optional (i.e. accepts other values outside the choices list)?

Comment: I think you cannot select values other than dropdown values..